# How to extract p-value from ur.df package of urca in R?

Tags: programming, statistics, stationarity

**I want to extract the p-value from the below output. How do i get it?**

```
library(urca)

data(Raotbl3)

attach(Raotbl3)

lc.df <- ur.df(y=lc, lags=3, type='trend')

summary(lc.df)
```

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `dput()` you can inspect an R object, e.g.

```
dput(lc.df)
```

Using that I found that the p-values are stored in an attribute `'testreg'` which turns out to be a list with class `summary.lm` (again with `dput()`). The coefficient table is in `coefficients` so getting the p-values is easy enough:

```
attr(lc.df, 'testreg')$coefficients[,4]
```

It's not unlikely that `urca` has a convenience method for this too.

Admittedly, finding the p-value of the whole test is a bit more tricky, the p-value is calculated on the fly as

```
1 - pf(3.07132302249161, 5, 89)
```

These values can be extracted from the object.

Comment: Im not able to fetch the p-value with the above code

Comment: > attr(lc.df, 'testreg')$coefficients[,4]
(Intercept)     z.lag.1          tt z.diff.lag1 z.diff.lag2 z.diff.lag3 
0.027024311 0.027658041 0.025174790 0.293449348 0.050021177 0.004203314

Comment: This is what i got by using your logic, im want p-value:0.01325(check the image)

Comment: Those are the same values as you show in the right column of your table? In any case, using `dput()` you should be able to be able to figure out how to get any value from that table.

Comment: thanks 1-pf() worked